# Fix width of the bar using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
y1 = df_1Q19[['capacity_bytes','failure']].groupby('capacity_bytes').sum() # Total number of failures by model
y2 = df_1Q19[['capacity_bytes','failure']].groupby('capacity_bytes').count() # Total number of each model
ptg_model_fail = np.divide(y1, y2) * 100 
ptg_model_fail.columns = ['ptg']
ptg_model_fail = ptg_model_fail.reset_index().sort_values('ptg')
# Set the colors
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.barh(ptg_model_fail['capacity_bytes'], ptg_model_fail['ptg'], color=colors,edgecolor='k',width=1)
ax.set_xlabel('Percentage')
ax.set_title('Failure percentage by model', size=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-078cb78058af> in <module>
      7 colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm']
      8 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
----> 9 ax.barh(ptg_model_fail['capacity_bytes'], ptg_model_fail['ptg'], color=colors,edgecolor='k',width=1)
     10 ax.set_xlabel('Percentage')
     11 ax.set_title('Failure percentage by size', size=16)

TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

I wanted to reduce the width of the following bar. I tried with width parameter, but I got an error. I used the following data to plot this bar chart. I appreciate suggestions.Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to set the height, not the width.

Comment: @BigBen height is not working!

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description of your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you provided has failure numbers, not percentages. I plotted it and it worked fine without adjustment. You can set the height of the horizontal bar as shown below.  Make sure your y-axis values are numerical, not strings.  Then set y-label to TB.

```
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.barh(ptg_model_fail['capacity_bytes'], ptg_model_fail['failure'], color=colors,edgecolor='k', height=1)
ax.set_xlabel('Failures')
ax.set_ylabel('TB')
ax.set_title('Failure by size', size=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]